# Text boxes that cover several pages

Tags: tables, boxes, minipage, mdframed

I am trying to faithfully reproduce the first section of the standard UK Police [Witness Statement Form](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/99023/response/250724/attach/5/RFI2012000015%20BlankWitness%20Statement.pdf), known as an MG11.

I am having difficulties lining up the boxes for the front page with the box that should contain the body of the statement.

More importantly the boxes allow text to run over several pages but this causes them to not have lines at the bottom or top of pages where it breaks. This also overlaps the Witness Statement header on subsequent pages. [image: the output of my code so far]

Here is the LaTeX code that generates my pdf so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\ihead{}
\chead{\\\framebox[1.1\width]{RESTRICTED}\\ \LARGE{Witness Statement}\\ \footnotesize{Criminal Procedure Rules, r 27.2; Criminal Justice Act 1967, s. 9; Magistrate's Courts Act 1980, s. 5B}\\}
\ohead{\\\framebox[1.1\width]{MG11} \vspace*{0.1 in} \\Page \textbf{\pagemark} of  \pageref{LastPage}}
\ifoot{Signature: \hdashrule{26em}{1pt}{1.5mm} Signature Witnessed by: \textbf{N/A}}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\begin{document}

% URN boxes drawn using table
\begin{table}
\vspace*{0.35 in}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\cline{2-5}
URN:& \multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{2em}}l|@{\hspace{2em}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|@{\hspace{2em}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|@{\hspace{2em}}}{} &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &\\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\end{table}

% Front page boxes drawn inside fboxes
\fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    Statement of: \textbf{John Smith}   \\ \\
    Age of witness: \textbf{Over 18}   {\hspace{23em}} Occupation: \textbf{Paper-pusher}\\

    This statement (consisting of \pageref{LastPage} pages each signed by me) is true to the best of my knowledge and belief and I make it knowing that, if it is tendered in evidence, I shall be liable to prosecution if I have wilfully stated in it, anything which I know to be false, or do not believe to be true.
    }
}
\fbox{
    \parbox[b][2em]{\textwidth}{
    Signature: \hdashrule{29em}{1pt}{1.5mm}   Date: \textbf{\today}
    }
}

% mdframed box for main textbox
\global\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
    linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,%
    leftmargin=0cm,rightmargin=0cm
}
\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
\Blindtext[14]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Please could anybody advise on how to fix the boxes so that they copy those found in the reference link?

Many thanks!

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  `tcolorbox` is often cited as an alternate to `mdframed`.  there are lots of questions here with `tcolorbox` as an answer, but i didn't find one that exactly duplicates your question, but if you search for `tcolorbox` and `frame` you will find a lot of useful information.

Comment: The `\fbox` is too wide because you did not take `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep` into account.

Comment: Are you sticking to `scrpage2`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I'm not especially attached to any package, I just care about the end result :-).

Answer (score 3):

A first trial with `tcolorbox` -- The main issue are the `header` and footer settings, leading to overlapping.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,top=1.25in,headheight=45pt,bottom=1in]{geometry}


\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\begin{tabular}[b]{c}\fbox{RESTRICTED}\tabularnewline\tabularnewline\multicolumn{1}{c}{\LARGE Witness Statement}\tabularnewline\multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize Criminal Procedure Rules, r 27.2; Criminal Justice Act 1967, s. 9; Magistrate's Courts Act 1980, s. 5B}\end{tabular}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\begin{tabular}[b]{|p{1.1cm}|}\hline MG11\tabularnewline\hline\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\tabularnewline \multicolumn{1}{l}{Page \textbf{\thepage} of  \pageref{LastPage}}\end{tabular}}
\fancyfoot[L]{Signature: \hdashrule{26em}{1pt}{1.5mm} Signature Witnessed by: \textbf{N/A}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\newlength{\effectiveboxwidth}
\setlength{\effectiveboxwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{tabular}{llllll}
  \cline{2-5}
  URN:& \multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{2em}}l|@{\hspace{2em}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|@{\hspace{2em}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|@{\hspace{2em}}}{} &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &\\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}


\tcbset{witness/.style={colframe=black,sharp corners,enhanced jigsaw, colback=white}} % Common settings

\begin{tcolorbox}[after={},witness]
  Statement of: \textbf{John Smith}   \par
  \vskip\baselineskip
  Age of witness: \textbf{Over 18}   \hfill  Occupation: \textbf{Paper-pusher}\\

  This statement (consisting of \pageref{LastPage} pages each signed by me) is true to the best of my knowledge and belief and I make it knowing that, if it is tendered in evidence, I shall be liable to prosecution if I have wilfully stated in it, anything which I know to be false, or do not believe to be true.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter,witness]
  Signature: \hdashrule{29em}{1pt}{1.5mm}   Date: \textbf{\today}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[witness,breakable,boxrule=1pt,toprule at break=1pt,extras={toprule at break=1pt} ]
\Blindtext[14]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The individual spacings must be adapted. I don't have the original form at hand.

[image]